# Get a list of components given the component name regardless they are nested - Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have the following sidebar in my app:

[image]

The tree item component code is :

```
 <!-- tree item template -->
 <script type="text/x-template" id="tree-item-template">
    <div>
        <div>
            <user-card @toggle-supervisor="toggle" :user_info="item" :key="item.id_user"></user-card>
        </div>
        <div v-show="isOpen" v-if="isFolder" class="ml-3">
            <tree-item
            v-for="(child, index) in item.employees"
            :key="index"
            :item="child"
            ></tree-item>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

This component contains another component called user-card inside it.

What i would like to get is an array with all of the components which name is 'user-card' regardless they are nested inside many other components.

The reason for this is because i want to change the color of the name to blue when a user is selected (clicked) and to black when the element is not selected

I found that using `this.$children` i can get the list of components inside a component, but not all of them, so i wonder if there is a way to get the list of all elements by the component name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this simple piece of code:

```js
        const child = this.$children.slice();
        const cards = [];
        let cur;
        while (child.length > 0)
        {
          cur = child.shift();
          if (cur.$options.name === 'user-card') cards.push(cur);
          else
          {
            cur = cur.$children.slice();
            for (let i = 0; i < cur.length; i++) child.push(cur[i]);
          }
        }
        // now you have your user cards inside the "cards" array
```

Comment: what does the slice() do in this case?

Comment: In this case `slice()` prevents you from destroying the original children array inside your component. Without it you will get strange behavior or even errors in the console.

Comment: It will create a new array to avoid an accidental call-by-reference. Similar to the spread `{ ...variable }` operator or "deep copies".

Comment: Slice and Spread do not make deep copies - the operate only on the first level of the hierarchy/nesting. For deep cloning there is [structurredClone()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone)